# How to close all active mysql/mariadb connections when your program is killed by SIGKILL?

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB with python. I have a small app with GUI built by PyQt5 and I need it to communicate with a MariaDB. I do use a separate IO thread for establishing connections and query my database. However, since I might have bugs in my program, sometimes the app freezes and I have to kill it from task manager (I'm using Windows but I assume that's same as SIGKILL in Linux). I then checked my remote database and I do find the connections I established are still alive.

Is there anyway to guarantee that I can close all my connections even when the program is killed by SIGKILL?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **no**

According to the [signal manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html):

The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

Comment: In that case, do I rely on the server side to automatically close the connect from timeout?

Comment: You could set interactive_timeout or wait_timeout server variables to a lower value - However best would be to fix your application, so it will not freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Always put critical code, that could raise an exception in try except finally

```
try:
     do something that can produce an error
 except:
     print("error connct")
 else:
     print("result is", result)
 finally:
     print("do something that will always be run)
```

see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html